# Get custom response from loopback login API

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I'm currently using Loopback3 to experiment and build a test application.

I've extended the default user model. When I use the login API on my custom user model I get a response like this -

```
{
  "id": "typIikmedhMiAoLketgdT4sOOTlSPGwZOFmol6wR6jF9RiZA4fAoKLYStKwyhbDA",
  "ttl": 1209600,
  "created": "2018-06-01T15:22:05.812Z",
  "userId": "5b0f8e00d831480db4670cbb"
}
```

But, I would also like to return other fields from my custom user model such as username along with the response from the login API. Is this something I can modify or do I have to resort to using userModel.find() to get other details that I would like the API to return?

What I would ideally like

```
{
  "id": "typIikmedhMiAoLketgdT4sOOTlSPGwZOFmol6wR6jF9RiZA4fAoKLYStKwyhbDA",
  "ttl": 1209600,
  "created": "2018-06-01T15:22:05.812Z",
  "userId": "5b0f8e00d831480db4670cbb",
  "username":"testAccount",
  "forcePasswordReset":true
}
```

I haven't attached any of my code since the question is related to just the default options on loopback framework and not specific to my code. If my code will help I will be happy to provide a sample. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible. Add `include=user` query param to the URL, like this:

```
POST /users/login?include=user
```

You should see:

```
{
   "id":"TOKEN",
   "ttl":1209600,
   "created":"2018-06-04T07:28:15.831Z",
   "userId":1,
   "user":{
      "realm":null,
      "username":"Test User",
      "email":"test@test.com",
      "emailVerified":true,
      "id":1
   }
}
```

Comment: What if you want to include a user relation in the response ?